# PHP SOAP Server protected by login/password

Tags: php, soap

I've created a new Soap Server that can be questioned about information about people. Now I'd like to protect this so only soapclients sending valid username and password can access to it.

I know I can send login/password as a parameter, but I don't like this solution. Is there a way to get and test login information sent by soapclient options array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use HTTP basic auth.

This way you can specify the user and password directly in the SOAP URL.

Comment: Any idea how to call the SoapClient to a WSDL protected by HTTP basic auth?

Answer (score -1):

Use of SAML 2.0 Single Sign On is more advantageous. You can set the artifact in Cookie. Initial SSO may use a basic HTTP authentication or domain specific methods.

http://www.opengroup.org/security/sso/

https://www.pingidentity.com/resource-center/SAML-Tutorials-and-Resources.cfm

It might help you

Comment: I'd like a more simple way :(